# Using regex to extract host names from Nagios cfg file

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, nagios

I have a config file from Nagios that I am successfully parsing to extract all the host_names. I can then use this information to compare to our server list to see if there is something that i am not monitoring. There are other ways to do this but it gives me an excuse to work on my Powershell and Regex. The pertinent sample from my config is:

> ```
> define host{
>     use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
>     host_name       server1         ; The name we're giving to this host
>     alias           server1         ; A longer name associated with the host
>     address         10.10.10.19     ; IP address of the host
>     }
>
> define host{
>     use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
>     host_name       server2         ; The name we're giving to this host
>     alias           server2         ; A longer name associated with the host
>     address         10.10.13.62     ; IP address of the host
>     }
>
> define host{
>     use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
>     host_name       server3         ; The name we're giving to this host
>     alias           server3         ; A longer name associated with the host
>     address         10.10.10.21     ; IP address of the host
>     }
>
> define service{   
>     use           generic-service     
>     hostgroup_name        windows-servers     
>     service_description   CPU Usage   
>     check_command     check_nrpe!alias_cpu    
>     }
>
> define service{   
>     use           generic-service     
>     host_name         server1     
>     service_description   Memory  
>     check_command     check_nrpe!alias_mem    
>     }
> ```

I have the following powershell snippet and regex queries

```
 $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("windows.cfg")
 $text | Select-String '(?smi)(?<=host\{).*?(?=\})' -AllMatches |
        Foreach {$_.Matches} |
        ForEach-Object {$_.Value} |
        Select-String '(?smi)(?<=host_name\s+)\w+' -AllMatches |
        Foreach {$_.Matches} |
        ForEach-Object {$_.Value}
```

I match the contents between host{ and } which makes sure i dont get extra hosts from service and hostgroup definitions. For each match for that i look for a whole word that exists after the static hostname and some whitespace.

It does work i just want to know if there is a more efficient or alternate regex approach. I tried to make it all one query but i could make it work so i had it nested as you can see in the code. Also i am to understand

Comment: `host\{[\s\S]*?\}` should suffice.

Comment: "extract all the host definitions" i realize now that the question can be misleading. I explicity wanted the hostname. so if a definition was `host_name       server1` i am trying to extract `server1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$text | Select-String 'host{[\s\S]*?}' -AllMatches | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups.Value
} | Select-String 'host_name\s*(\S+)' | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

There may be a way to do this with a single regular expression (not sure about it), but the above is probably easier to understand and to maintain.

Comment: Looking at your response makes me realize how unnecessarily complicated i was making my regex. I was essentially trying to use non-capture groups and in Powershell that is apparently accomplisehed by using lookaheads. Your code produced no output unless i used 'Foreach {$_.Matches} |
        ForEach-Object {$_.Value}` like in my example. My powershell version is 2 by the way. $_.Matches does contain the matches fyi.

Comment: @Matt I was assuming that you were using at least PowerShell v3. You should upgrade if you can.

Comment: Most of the machines in my org use 2. Upgrading, at the very least my own system, is on my list of things to do. While I was fishing for a regex one liner your answer addresses the efficiency component of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I usually approach that kind of problem like this:

```
(@'
define host{
    use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name       server1         ; The name we're giving to this host
    alias           server1         ; A longer name associated with the host
    address         10.10.10.19     ; IP address of the host
    }

define host{
    use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name       server2         ; The name we're giving to this host
    alias           server2         ; A longer name associated with the host
    address         10.10.13.62     ; IP address of the host
    }

define host{
    use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name       server3         ; The name we're giving to this host
    alias           server3         ; A longer name associated with the host
    address         10.10.10.21     ; IP address of the host
    }

define service{   
    use           generic-service     
    hostgroup_name        windows-servers     
    service_description   CPU Usage   
    check_command     check_nrpe!alias_cpu    
    }

define service{   
    use           generic-service     
    host_name         server1     
    service_description   Memory  
    check_command     check_nrpe!alias_mem    
    }
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} | set-content windows.cfg

get-content windows.cfg -ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {$_ -match '^\s*host_name' -replace '^\s*host_name\s+(\S+).+','$1'}

server1
server2
server3
server1
```

Using Get-Content with -ReadCount lets you work with the file data in controllable chunks, so you don't have memory issues if you throw a large file at it.  Since it's passing arrays of strings down the pipeline, the -match and replace are working as array operators, doing the entire array at once, the -match filtering out the host_name records, and then the -replace extracting the value from the string.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity and know how you value here strings. `foreach {$_ -match '^\s*host_name' -replace '^\s*host_name\s+(\S+).+','$1'}` matches service and hostgroup definitions as well so the output wont be initially unique hostnames without manipulating the list. Also the output i would have expected from your code should have been the following 
    `server1
    server2
    server3
    server1`
as 'server' is not a hostname in my example

Comment: The 'server' value was a copy/paste error (should have been 'server1' from the last match)  That's my fault, not the script. I didn't realize you needed the values to be unique, but that's relatively trivial to accomplish either after the fact, or in-stream using a hash table.

Comment: I agree with the trivial comment. This purpose of this question was to examine regex possibilities or other ways to extract the data which you did accomplish.

Comment: If i copy and past that code in your answer i still get 'server' as part of the results. Does that not happen when you run it?